# Is multivariable calculus synonymous with differential geometry?

Tags: differential-geometry, multivariable-calculus

Or are they two distinct topics?  For instance, Spivak's calculus on manifolds book considered  a treatise on multivariable calculus, but concludes with a differential geometry theorem - Stokes' theorem.

Comment: (Multvariable) calculus is the tool to study geometry in differential geometry. So yes, they are two different things.

Comment: I don't think that I would call Stokes' theorem *differential geometry*

Comment: Multivariable calculus = local differential geometry.

Comment: Is calculus synonymous with linear algebra?